# OpenLayers Label styling (font size)

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I have a polygon dataset that I am symbolizing in OpenLayers using a context to determine the correct color, and also a label for each polygon that I want to alter depending on the zoom level.

But although my polygons get colored as they should, my labels don't change. If I test this with a point feature and no symbolization, my labels do change the way I want. So I guess this is something to do with the way rules and context are applied? How can I fix this so that the labels change size with the rules?

```
var ratingStyle = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
            fillColor: "${getColor}",
            strokeColor: "#000000",
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            graphicZIndex: 1,
            label: "${ADMINUNIT}",
            labelAlign: 'cm',
            labelOutlineColor: "white",
            labelOutlineWidth: 3,
            fontSize: 12,
            fontOpacity: 1
        }, {
            context: { //this is for the polygon color
                getColor: function (feature) {
                    return feature.attributes.RATING == 'NotRated' ? 'transparent' :
                    feature.attributes.RATING == 'Low' ? 'green' :
                    feature.attributes.RATING == 'Moderate' ? 'yellow' :
                    feature.attributes.RATING == 'High' ? 'red' :
                    feature.attributes.RATING == 'Extreme' ? 'black' :
                    'grey';
                }
            }
        }, { //rules for labels?
            rules: [
                new OpenLayers.Rule({
                    minScaleDenominator: 50000000,
                    symbolizer: {
                        fontSize: "0px"
                    }
                }),
                new OpenLayers.Rule({
                    maxScaleDenominator: 50000000,
                    minScaleDenominator: 20000000,
                    symbolizer: {
                        fontSize: "10px"
                    }
                }),
                new OpenLayers.Rule({
                    maxScaleDenominator: 20000000,
                    symbolizer: {
                        fontSize: "12px"
                    }
                })
            ]
        }),
        "select": new OpenLayers.Style({
            fillOpacity: 1,
            graphicZIndex: 1
        })
    }, {
        extendDefault: true
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to realize the scale-dependent font size with a second context-function? You can get the scale with map.getScale()

Comment: This was the way to go, stacking up contexts.

Answer (score 0):

For reference:

```
    fillColor: "${getColor}",
    fontSize: "${fontSizer}",
 }, { context: {
        getColor : function (feature) {
            return feature.attributes.RATING == 'NotRated' ? 'transparent':
                   feature.attributes.RATING == 'Low' ? 'green':
                   feature.attributes.RATING == 'Moderate' ? 'yellow':
                   feature.attributes.RATING == 'High' ? 'red':
                   feature.attributes.RATING == 'Extreme' ? 'black':
                   'grey';
        },
        fontSizer : function () {
            if (label_bool) { //labels on
                scale = map.getScale();
                if (scale > 30000000) {
                    return "0px";
                } else if (scale > 8000000) {
                    return "8px";
                } else {
                    return "12px";
                }
            } else { //labels off
                return "0px";
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I didn't realize this was on the GIS Stack Exchange instead of the main one :(